# JavaScript dialogArguments._IE_PrintType SCRIPT5002 error in IE11 on Windows 7

Tags: javascript

I'm testing our web application - print function in IE11 on Windows 7.
I got the SCRIPT5002:function expected js error when print document.
the error happened in preview.js which is IE explorer's own js.

"dialogArguments._IE_PrintType = PrintManager - SCRIPT5002:function expected"

the javascript print function I used is window.print.

kindly help to indicate how to fix it.
thanks in advance.

below is the screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMJ4M.png

Comment: the javascript print funtion I used is : window.print.

Comment: please attach your source code

Comment: <script>
window.print();
window.close();
</script>
this is the print function code.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you close the window immediatly after print command. `window.print` take some time to fire, the window must stay open. Try this instead :

```
window.print();
window.onfocus=function(){ this.close();}
```

Comment: indeed I'm also noted this point. but not sure why it worked well on IE8 while on IE 11 it has error.

Comment: Just two different implementations of the print function in two different browsers.

Comment: thank you Freez, issue is resolved with your solution.